# Batch: CHKDSK for D:\ without query at restart

Tags: batch-file

I want to check C: and D: (C: is the primary drive) via a batch file.
the trick is to get it done without a query or request, it should just make the task and check at the next boot. 
My solution for C: is `echo j | chkdsk C: /f /r` but this doesn't work for D: because of the two request wich would make that task but like i mentioned befor, the script should work completely autonomous, no question no query, just a double click a manual restart an a full CHKDS at reboot.

Comment: I think, C will be forced to check at next reboot, because it is in use. Try creating a temp file/directory somewhere on D: & then immediately (before fs gets synced) run the same command for D:. You may need to keep writing junk to that temp file, to keep D:\ file system busy, when you issue the chkdsk command.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it good, what you want is to perform a scan of a secondary drive at boot time, but you can't scan any other drive than "C:\" (system drive) at boot-time.

So, no solution for this, sorry.